# How to access value of Arraylist in android

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have one Hash-map that returns an `ArrayList` and  stored in another `ArrayList` now I don't know how to access it. The main issue is I don't know the index number of the hash-map return value.

What I tried.

```
ArrayList<MenuDetail> mdetail;
HashMap<String,ArrayList<MenuDetail>> RTMenuThemeYellow;
for(int i = 0;i < ResponseString.getRights().length;i++)
{
   mdetail = RTMenuThemeYellow.get(ResponseString.getRights()[i]);
   if(mdetail != null)
   {  
   }
}
```

Now how do I access the value from the `mdetail` variable

Comment: mdetail is array list so you can access mdetail.get(i) which is return an object of MenuDetail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving an element from array list in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664168/retrieving-an-element-from-array-list-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

How i accessed value from mdetail variable?

```
mdetail.get(i);
```

'i' is the index -- in your for loop